# time complexity between a ordered map string search vs int search

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the time complexity taken by the ordered map's find function. For example

**test.cpp**

```
map1<std::string, int> = {["name1", 1],["name2", 2],["name3", 3],["name4", 4]};
map2<int, int> = {[1, 10],[2, 20],[3, 30],[4, 40]};
```

Now the worst time complexity would be:

```
map2.find(2) // would be O(log n)
map1.find("name2") // would be O(log n) + length("name2")
```

Is the worst time complexity right for the map2? if not could anyone please explain?

Comment: According to [this `std::map::find` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) the complexity is "[l]ogarithmic in the size of the container". That's it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: But in string search it has to compare every character, so how can it be just log(n). In this example it has to compare for atleast 4 character.

Comment: Because that's how [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) works: If you have two complexities the potentially bigger one "wins" and the smaller is not used.

Comment: The complexity measurement is meant to describe how the algorithm scales. If you have a large enough map, the cost of string comparisons become irrelevant compared to the cost of the search itsef. And for the small map there is no point at all to bother with complexity. If you wanted to be percise, and factor in the comparison cost (for example if the string is very long), i think the correct complexity would be: O(M*log(N)), here M is the length of string.

Comment: The declarations of `map1` and `map2` is _not_ valid C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the worst time complexity right for the map2?

What is right depends on what complexity you are analysing. The logarithmic complexity of map lookup describes the number of comparisons between elements of the map. This is the same regardless of the type of the element in the map.

If you analyse the complexity in terms of sub-operations of the comparison function, then the total complexity will be a product of the lookup complexity, and the worst case complexity of the comparison (assuming we are analysing worst case complexity, and not average).

The complexity (number of character comparisons) of a string comparison is linear in terms the length of the longest common initial substring between the strings.

So, the complexity of comparison sub operations of a string map lookup is O(m * log n), where n is the size of the map, and m is the length of the longest common initial substring of the elements of the map. The upper bound for m is the length of the longest string.